# Safe way to process passage with quote and double quote in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

Suppose I am importing a passage by file_get_contents() or getting user input, there may be single quotes or double quotes or both. What is the safe way to cast the said content into a variable and do manipulation afterward?

Comment: There are only security vulnerabilities if you pass that data to other functions (such as not binary safe functions, database queries without prepared statements) or if you output it without proper escaping (htmlspecialchars()).

Comment: What kind of "insecurity" are you expecting here and what exactly are you doing? This question doesn't make much sense as is.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You see what I want to do the escaping after casting the passage into a variable. But I cannot cast the variable in the first place if the passage would contains both single quote and double quote. And the sources are external json or xml files.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are about to do with the input later on:

---

**Output  as HTML:**

```
$input = htmlspecialchars($input);
```

**Use it in a shell command:**

```
$input = escapeshellarg($input);
```

**Use it in a database query**

If you use prepared statements you are fine. If not (why?), use:

```
$input = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $string);
// or
$input = PDO::quote($input);

// other database extension may introduce their own quoting functions
```

**Use it in a regular expression:**

```
$input = preg_quote($input);
```

---

Extension or correction of this list is appreciated.... :)

Comment: Thank you that is a very helpful lists. But in my case turns out I worried too much. I am using simplexml_load_file to process an xml file that consist both single quote and double quote. Hence I worry there would be error. But it turns out php can actually handle that correctly. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: Yes, in that case you worried too much! :)